# Showing % in pyplot text using f-string with `usetex` enabled

Tags: python, matplotlib, format

I was trying to use f-string to show percentages in the title of a pyplot image. However, I cannot get the `{:.2%}` to work.

**EDIT**: I am using jupyter notebook with `usetex` enabled

Here is a very basic example to repro:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
a = 0.12345
plt.title(f'This is {a:.2%} and some text')
# Prints "Text(0.5, 1.0, 'This is 12.35% and some Text')"
```

[image]

It looks like the number is formatted correctly, but pyplot is failing to show the `%` + anything after it. Same thing happens if I try `plt.title('This is {:.2%} and some text'.format(a))`.

**EDIT**: It looks like this happens if `rc.text.usetex = True` is set. I guess the question becomes, how do I use `%` format specifier in pyplot with LaTeX enabled?

**UPDATE 1**: I can get it to work if I replace all the `%` symbols: `plt.title(f'This is {a:.2%} and some text'.replace('%', '\%'))`. I wonder if there is a way to avoid the `replace`? The reason is that sometimes I enable the `usetex` and sometimes I don't. When TeX is not used it prints `\%` verbatim :(

Comment: works as expected for me.

Comment: OK, I set the `text.usetex` to `False`, and it fixed it. I guess the question is how do I use it with `usetex` enabled? I Will update the question -- thanks